# Python: Column and Row operations without using loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a the below `df1`:

```
  Date        Tickers Qty
01-01-2018    ABC    25
02-01-2018    BCD    25
02-01-2018    XYZ    31
05-01-2018    XYZ    25
```

and another `df2` as below

```
  Date         ABC  BCD  XYZ
01-01-2018    123   5   78
02-01-2018    125   7   79
03-01-2018    127   6   81
04-01-2018    126   7   82
05-01-2018    124   6   83
```

I want a resultant column in `df1` which is the product of the correct column and row in `df2` - getting the right ticker's rate on the given date and let the other dates have nan within `df1`

```
  Date       df1['Product']
01-01-2018      3075
02-01-2018      175
02-01-2018      2449
03-01-2018      nan
04-01-2018      nan
05-01-2018      2075
```

This seems like standard python operation, but I just am unable to achieve this without writing a loop - which is taking a very long time to execute:

I merged the above 2 tables on `Date` and then ran the below loop

```
for i in range(len(df1)):
    try:
        df1['Product'][i] = df1[df1['Ticker'][i]][i]
    except ValueError:
        df['Product'][i] = np.nan
```

Is there any better pythonic way of achieving this and not writing this loop pls?

Comment: I would like to add that i could have more than one tickers on a given date and so using date as a pure index may not help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
df11 = df1.pivot('Date', 'Tickers','Qty')
df22 = df2.set_index('Date')

s = df22.mul(df11).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (s)
Date
01-01-2018     3075.0
02-01-2018      175.0
03-01-2018        NaN
04-01-2018        NaN
05-01-2018     2075.0
Name: ABC, dtype: float64
```

Solution for add new column to `df1`:

```
df11 = df1.pivot('Date', 'Tickers','Qty')
df22 = df2.set_index('Date')

df = df1.join(df22.mul(df11).stack().rename('new'), on=['Date','Tickers'], how='left')
print (df)
         Date Tickers  Qty     new
0  01-01-2018     ABC   25  3075.0
1  02-01-2018     BCD   25   175.0
2  05-01-2018     XYZ   25  2075.0
```

EDIT:

If pairs `Date`s with `Tickers` are duplicated, solution above is not possible use.

```
print (df1)
         Date Tickers  Qty
0  01-01-2018     ABC   25
1  01-01-2018     ABC   20 <-added duplicated pairs 01-01-2018 and ABC
2  02-01-2018     XYZ   31
3  02-01-2018     BCD   25
4  05-01-2018     XYZ   25

df3 = df1[['Date']].copy()
#add new values to column
df3['new'] = df2.set_index('Date').lookup(df1['Date'], df1['Tickers']) * df1['Qty']
#add missing values to duplicated Dates 
df3 = df2[['Date']].drop_duplicates().merge(df3, how='left') 
print (df3)
         Date     new
0  01-01-2018  3075.0
1  01-01-2018  2460.0
2  02-01-2018  2449.0
3  02-01-2018   175.0
4  03-01-2018     NaN
5  04-01-2018     NaN
6  05-01-2018  2075.0
```

Comment: `df11 = df1.pivot('Date', 'Tickers','Qty')`
gives 
`ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: apologies for wasting your time so far by not providing the info that there can be multiple tickers on a single date..

Comment: @spiff - Yes, sure. Give me some time.

Comment: @spiff - Unfortunately duplicates complicated solution, so create another one.

Answer (score 3):

you need to set 'Date' as index and multiply,

```
df1=df1.set_index('Date')
df2=df2.set_index('Date')


df3=(df2['ABC']*df1['Qty']).reset_index() 
print(df3)
    Date        0
0   01-01-2018  3075.0
1   02-01-2018  3125.0
2   03-01-2018  NaN
3   04-01-2018  NaN
4   05-01-2018  3100.0
```

Comment: thanks vm - but i think this may not work if I have more than one tickers on the same date?
Edit: maybe I should have explained that in my example itself, apologies for that